# SQLite - Group Concat and Distinct

Tags: database, sqlite

Good Morning,

I want to request a SQLite database.
For example, i want to print every name for every town and group name in the result.

My request look like this :

```
SELECT Town, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name,';')
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE action IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Town;
```

The "';'" in the GROUP_CONCAT specify the delimiter i want to use. If i use DISTINCT and the delimiter option, it returns me this ERROR :

> Error: DISTINCT aggregates must have exactly one argument

If i use DISTINCT without the delimiter option, it works, and if i use the delimiter without the DISTINCT, it works too.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try first using a subquery to yield all distinct names for each town.  Then, do your current aggregation:

```
SELECT
    Town, GROUP_CONCAT(name, ';')
FROM
(
    SELECT Town, name
    FROM MY_TABLE
    WHERE action IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Town, name
) t
GROUP BY Town;
```